# ZedGraph не хочет работать с DataGridView (C#)

Tags: c#, datagridview, zedgraph

Есть переменные у меня двух стилей 
1)Такой пишет ошибку, что **Входная строка имела неверный формат** или **Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта.**

`double x = double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value.ToString());
double y = double.Parse(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value.ToString());`

или есть такого вида: (он строит только одну точну в координаты 0.0).

```
double x =  Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
double y = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
```

Сам код выглядит так:

```
    zedGraph1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear ();
            for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
            {
double x =  Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
 double y = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    zedGraph1.Invalidate ();
  PointPairList f1_list = new PointPairList ();


               f1_list.Add(x,y);
                    LineItem f1_curve = zedGraph1.GraphPane.AddCurve (" ", f1_list, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
                    zedGraph1.AxisChange ();
zedGraph1.Invalidate ();

                }
```

Суть кода:
Должен брать данные с 1 и 3 столбца и выстроить их на график.
Вопрос:
Как мне решить эту делему, где я и что делаю не так? Формат в таблице Double.

Comment: Пишет все правильно, потому что dataGridView2.Rows[...].Cells[...].Value может быть null или содержать строку, которая совершенно не обязана быть числом. Конвертирование обязательно должно быть в try{} catch()

Comment: Я с таким не сталкивался особо, но каким костылём я сделаю по строчную проверку try catch в массиве данных?

Comment: @ElemStack сделайте простой цикл и выполните TryParse.

Comment: Система Вам пишет: "...Входная строка имела неверный формат или Ссылка на объект не указывает на экземпляр объекта..." - Вы уже столкнулись и с тем, и с другим. Не нравиться try{} catch()  внутри цикла - используйте TryToPase(...).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проще показать ответом:

```
zedGraph1.GraphPane.CurveList.Clear ();

double x=0,y=0;
for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView2.Rows.Count ; i++)
{
    try
    {
        x =  Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[0].Value);
        y = Convert.ToDouble(dataGridView2.Rows[i].Cells[2].Value);
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        //Обрабатываете Exception - пишите в лог или выводите e.Message на панель
        ......

        //Переходите к следующей строке таблицы
        continue;
    }

    //Далее Ваш код, на который Вы не жаловались и который я не анализировал
    zedGraph1.Invalidate ();
    PointPairList f1_list = new PointPairList ();


    f1_list.Add(x,y);
    LineItem f1_curve = zedGraph1.GraphPane.AddCurve (" ", f1_list, System.Drawing.Color.Red);
    zedGraph1.AxisChange ();
    zedGraph1.Invalidate ();

}
```